# Why does iMessage recipient show as green when sending message thru Siri Shortcuts?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, shortcuts-app

I'm trying to use the built in "ETA" shortcut recipe. I add my wife as the recipient and run the shortcut. When it shows me the message for confirmation, her name is green, not blue.

When I actually send the message and look in the Messages app, I now have two different conversations for her. One is our historic message thread, the other has only this single message sent by Shortcuts.

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Are you sending it to her Apple ID email address or to her phone number?  What's different between how she's being contacted for both threads in Messages?

Comment: This is a common glitch with shortcuts. I have found now solution so far but I will keep looking.

Comment: Try typing in your wife's email address she uses for iMessage, not phone number.

Comment: She uses an iPad, so iMessage is through her email. Tonight I tried it again. This time the bubble is blue, but it’s still listed in messages as a separate conversation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by typing in the phone number rather than using the contact.